# SSL_accept returns SSL_ERROR_SSL

Tags: c++, sockets, openssl, ssl-certificate, nonblocking

I have a strange error working with openssl in c++ with non blocking sockets.

SSL_accept return SSL_ERROR_SSL.
error string is

> "error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol"

as obtained from

```
ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL);
```

**ssldump:**

```
New TCP connection #1: localhost(35677) <-> localhost(8084)
1 1  1443513828.4788 (0.0001)  C>SV3.1(153)  Handshake
      ClientHello
        Version 3.3 
        random[32]=
          e9 fc d9 2b 25 20 77 9f 5f a4 b1 eb 5d 50 15 f2 
          38 7a a9 86 16 49 f8 a3 e9 00 7f 93 11 cd 7b b1 
        cipher suites
        Unknown value 0xc02b
        Unknown value 0xc02f
        Unknown value 0xc00a
        Unknown value 0xc009
        Unknown value 0xc013
        Unknown value 0xc014
        Unknown value 0xc012
        Unknown value 0xc007
        Unknown value 0xc011
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        Unknown value 0x45
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        Unknown value 0x88
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        Unknown value 0x41
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        Unknown value 0x84
        TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
        compression methods
                  NULL
1 2  1443513828.4790 (0.0002)  S>CV3.3(53)  Handshake
      ServerHello
        Version 3.3 
        random[32]=
          aa d6 10 d1 eb b5 de b1 ed f8 6b 2f 44 fa 9f 57 
          14 1d c0 27 a1 e9 24 3a 20 cb 09 fa 75 33 1c c7 
        session_id[0]=
        cipherSuite         TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        compressionMethod                   NULL
1 3  1443513828.4790 (0.0000)  S>CV3.3(1003)  Handshake
      Certificate
        certificate[993]=
          30 82 03 dd 30 82 02 c5 a0 03 02 01 02 02 09 00 
          bc 6b da c1 c3 f0 3f 14 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 
          f7 0d 01 01 0b 05 00 30 81 84 31 0b 30 09 06 03 
          55 04 06 13 02 49 4e 31 0b 30 09 06 03 55 04 08 
          0c 02 49 4e 31 10 30 0e 06 03 55 04 07 0c 07 67 
          75 72 67 61 6f 6e 31 0e 30 0c 06 03 55 04 0a 0c 
          05 69 72 65 78 78 31 0c 30 0a 06 03 55 04 0b 0c 
          03 64 65 76 31 12 30 10 06 03 55 04 03 0c 09 6c 
          6f 63 61 6c 68 6f 73 74 31 24 30 22 06 09 2a 86 
          48 86 f7 0d 01 09 01 16 15 76 69 6b 61 73 73 6f 
          6f 64 31 31 40 67 6d 61 69 6c 2e 63 6f 6d 30 1e 
          17 0d 31 35 30 39 32 39 30 38 30 32 35 36 5a 17 
          0d 31 36 30 39 32 38 30 38 30 32 35 36 5a 30 81 
          84 31 0b 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 49 4e 31 0b 
          30 09 06 03 55 04 08 0c 02 49 4e 31 10 30 0e 06 
          03 55 04 07 0c 07 67 75 72 67 61 6f 6e 31 0e 30 
          0c 06 03 55 04 0a 0c 05 69 72 65 78 78 31 0c 30 
          0a 06 03 55 04 0b 0c 03 64 65 76 31 12 30 10 06 
          03 55 04 03 0c 09 6c 6f 63 61 6c 68 6f 73 74 31 
          24 30 22 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 09 01 16 15 
          76 69 6b 61 73 73 6f 6f 64 31 31 40 67 6d 61 69 
          6c 2e 63 6f 6d 30 82 01 22 30 0d 06 09 2a 86 48 
          86 f7 0d 01 01 01 05 00 03 82 01 0f 00 30 82 01 
          0a 02 82 01 01 00 e2 9e cb 0c 9a c2 a4 0a ff 81 
          77 23 ad 74 c6 a0 12 9f f4 a4 86 94 bf 02 57 cc 
          ff 13 cf 4f 13 83 6e 70 8b 2d ee 92 93 94 44 d4 
          db 20 e1 67 65 3a 67 c1 d5 91 67 ab f9 98 aa 59 
          16 b4 38 99 92 66 c2 de e7 88 82 cd a0 10 95 89 
          78 f5 64 6a e5 b6 75 a2 e0 d0 76 c3 57 92 03 c7 
          d3 7d f3 c5 18 e5 bf 8d f5 71 17 4c dd 18 fa 11 
          8c d1 ed 8b 0f b6 5c fb 16 bf 5a 44 23 71 c8 83 
          83 5a 4d ca b0 8c 15 96 66 dc cd 9a 06 33 b3 eb 
          71 43 25 b1 0f df 1a c6 f1 7a 4c 4d 5e 34 12 b7 
          70 76 b6 f9 7e 40 6c 2e 70 df 26 cd f9 c9 0b 90 
          57 dd 0b c3 57 b8 55 ad 63 13 16 15 bf 8d 3b 48 
          9d 11 cf 15 55 a1 f2 ab ff 8f 43 48 09 e7 c9 b0 
          21 66 e7 e4 76 14 aa d4 a9 88 ef bf e1 db 0f b3 
          27 95 d0 c9 50 6f 36 c8 5e 47 3f c3 a8 59 9c a6 
          8a 75 57 0b db 83 c6 08 13 fa 9c 64 3c 5a 4e d5 
          ba 4f 23 39 67 77 02 03 01 00 01 a3 50 30 4e 30 
          1d 06 03 55 1d 0e 04 16 04 14 29 86 80 ff 9c 14 
          00 5e 2e 89 81 4a 1e 3c 32 82 ec 44 35 7b 30 1f 
          06 03 55 1d 23 04 18 30 16 80 14 29 86 80 ff 9c 
          14 00 5e 2e 89 81 4a 1e 3c 32 82 ec 44 35 7b 30 
          0c 06 03 55 1d 13 04 05 30 03 01 01 ff 30 0d 06 
          09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 01 0b 05 00 03 82 01 01 
          00 c9 f4 f7 0f bd a4 f2 81 e4 4e c5 4d 86 9d f3 
          30 fe df f6 b1 b5 a3 a6 ef 41 51 fc f3 1b c5 be 
          e1 1f 75 fe f1 ee 94 95 54 c7 07 13 d4 b6 89 2b 
          a3 86 e3 7b 12 6d 0a 51 66 31 74 d5 83 67 92 79 
          45 b3 03 1d 77 6b b0 71 a0 07 c0 06 e6 6b 81 74 
          01 8e 6d a6 c1 82 8b 34 b2 6c 52 b9 3e a6 c0 c5 
          ce f6 c8 b2 4b 6a 8c 43 4a 20 38 61 8a 09 1f 39 
          cd e6 4a 0b 6c 89 b8 88 74 d7 1e fa 86 dc 0a cd 
          d4 73 39 5f 53 4b 13 79 f8 cd 62 ee 38 42 61 56 
          26 31 44 ac 5b 39 24 2b 3f f9 21 b4 59 25 14 95 
          69 e6 33 41 df ef b5 ea 20 7d 38 a9 f4 c3 d1 f7 
          c5 37 4a c9 01 cd f4 3a e7 3c a7 16 33 0f 5d 46 
          19 bc 50 3d 33 05 63 ee 29 51 d1 79 c4 01 04 0f 
          be 27 65 57 ab e5 e8 d3 bf 4d 11 55 bc 52 e4 9f 
          d9 0c 87 be a9 62 9d be 65 21 a8 8a 46 63 d1 91 
          f9 2b e1 c6 5d 33 fb ae b6 9e a0 36 0b 37 2a fa 
          3b 
1 4  1443513828.4790 (0.0000)  S>CV3.3(4)  Handshake
      ServerHelloDone
1 5  1443513828.4800 (0.0009)  C>SV3.3(262)  Handshake
      ClientKeyExchange
        EncryptedPreMasterSecret[256]=
          76 58 13 c2 dd ed fb 6e 7b 49 aa 0c 26 40 a1 1f 
          8b 87 b0 f6 a5 f8 24 fe 0c 7b a9 e6 b0 51 b1 92 
          2c 52 33 ba af 2a d2 52 b8 80 0f ea fd 24 b7 89 
          15 2f 0e 90 86 ef 9c 9d 52 02 ca 56 09 b5 81 5f 
          e1 05 a8 9a 44 32 7f 4f ec 58 33 4a 97 96 23 15 
          7d a8 1d 8c bc 5d 20 13 39 54 2f 61 27 be aa 6a 
          ec 49 be 82 cc 2b c7 3d a3 b0 cb 4f 26 cb 14 41 
          d4 4b 00 57 6f 52 2b 66 aa 23 97 ed e9 e7 9c d9 
          ed 81 28 0c 08 9f dd 9d e4 00 b5 ba aa a4 f6 3b 
          23 87 f6 da 64 c0 1e 33 87 bb ef bc c3 fe 28 64 
          d1 c8 ff ae f9 3f 5a fe 38 e6 ab 3e 34 2c b5 96 
          f7 a8 99 b6 8e b3 46 d3 c9 f8 f8 94 26 97 27 85 
          5f 3e ff 85 15 5f c8 1f 10 53 26 e4 88 32 4f 48 
          62 87 ac a8 9f 14 f1 e3 f4 c4 1a 71 49 e6 33 15 
          16 66 66 ec 68 ee f7 91 0c 4c b3 3a 49 88 e1 31 
          a5 fe 4c 31 35 3d dc 01 f6 be f2 e5 65 a0 bb 78 
1 6  1443513828.4800 (0.0000)  C>SV3.3(1)  ChangeCipherSpec
1 7  1443513828.4800 (0.0000)  C>SV3.3(64)  Handshake
Unknown SSL content type 72
1    1443513828.4801 (0.0001)  S>C  TCP RST
```

I am not sure why the server resets the connection.

I am using a self signed certificate to test a websocket connection using scheme wss. Client is Mozilla Firefox and websocket server is what I am trying to implement.

Any pointers on why the server is resetting the connection?

error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol

What possible reason could throw unknown protocol?

Thanks

Edited: Adding code. It is not all the code but gives a fair idea of what i did.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
/*
    this the main method that accepts incoming connection on a listening socket.
*/
SecureServer::Accept()
{
    int ret = 0;
    while(!mFinished) {
    ret = epoll_wait(millis);

    if(ret == -1) {
        continue;
    }

    else if(ret == 0) {
        idle(0);
    }

    else if(ret > 0) {
        //some events are triggered
        for(int i=0; i<ret; i++) {
        
        //getEvent method is in the base class.
        //SecureServer is derived from this class. 
        //Base class is just an epoll wrapper
        epoll_event* ev = getEvent(i);
        
        //check for error
        if( (ev->events & EPOLLERR) || (ev->events & EPOLLHUP) || !(ev->events & EPOLLIN)) {
            ERROR(Log::eSecureServer, "Error occured on fd = %d", ev->data.fd);
            removeEpollFd(ev->data.fd);
            continue;
        }
    
        //check if its a new incoming connection on server socket
        else if(ev->data.fd == mServerSocket) {
            //accept the connection
                    struct sockaddr peerAddress;
                    socklen_t socklen = sizeof(peerAddress);

                    int newSocket = accept(mSocket, &peerAddress, &socklen);
                    if(newSocket == -1) {
                        ERROR(Log::eSecureServer, "Error in accept, listen address = %s, port = %d epoll_wait returned = %d", mHost.c_str(), mPort, ret);
                        continue;
                    }

                    rxUShort port = ntohs(*((rxUShort*) &(peerAddress.sa_data[0])));

                    char ipPort[32] = {0};

                    sprintf(ipPort, "%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu:%hu", peerAddress.sa_data[2],peerAddress.sa_data[3],peerAddress.sa_data[4],
                            peerAddress.sa_data[5],port);

                    INFO(Log::eSecureServer, "SecureTCPServer received incoming client connection from = %s", ipPort);

            //add epoll fd
            // This method also makes the socket NON BLOCKING
                    addEpollFd(newSocket);  
        }

        //check the handshake from a previously accepted connection
        else {
            //process the handshake
            processHandshake(ev->data.fd);
        }
        }
    }
    }
}


/*
    This method determines the client and server protocol
*/
int Protocol::processHandshake(int fd) 
{
    int length = 0;

    length = recv(fd, handshake, 1024, MSG_PEEK);
    if(length == 0) {
    return UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL;
    }

    else if((bcmp(handshake, "\x16", 1) == 0) ||
               (bcmp(handshake, "\x80", 1) == 0)) {
    
    //secure connection requested on this fd
    SSL* pSSL = 0;
    int ret = NewSSLSocket(pSSL, fd);
    if(SSL_ERROR_NON == ret) {
        ///success
    }

    else {
            if(SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ == ret || SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE == ret) {
            NFO(Log::eProtocol, "Handshake error, in progress.");
            return eProtocolHandshakeInProgress;
            } else if(SSL_ERROR_SSL == ret) {
            INFO(Log::eProtocol, "Handshake error, library error");
            return eProtocolInvalidHeader;
            } else if(SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL == ret) {
            INFO(Log::eProtocol, "Handshake error, possibly syscall error");
            return eProtocolInvalidHeader;
            }
            SSL_free(pSSL);
    }
    }
}


int Protocol::NewSSLSocket(SSL* pSSL, rxUInt fd)
{
    pSSL = SSL_new(mSSLContext);
    SSL_set_fd(pSSL, fd);

    int ret = SSL_accept(pSSL);
    switch(SSL_get_error(pSSL, ret)) {
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
        case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
        {
            INFO(Log::eNetwork, "SSL Handshake is in progress on fd = %d %s", fd, ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
            return SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ;
        }
        break;
        case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
        {
            INFO(Log::eNetwork, "SSL syscall error during handshake on fd = %d %s", fd, ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
            return SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL;
        }
        break;
        case SSL_ERROR_SSL:
        {
            INFO(Log::eNetwork, "SSL library error during handshake on fd = %d %s", fd, ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
            return SSL_ERROR_SSL;
        }
        case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
        {
            INFO(Log::eNetwork, "SSL handshake on fd = %d complete", fd);
            return SSL_ERROR_NONE;
        }
        break;
        default:
        {
            INFO(Log::eNetwork, "SSL unknown error during handshake on fd = %d %s", fd, ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
            return -1;
        }
        break;
    }
    return -1;
}

//Protocol Constructor Init the SSL Context
Protocol::Protocol()
{
    const SSL_METHOD* pSSLMethod = SSLv23_server_method();
    char err[1024] = {0};
    
    mSSLContext = SSL_CTX_new(pSSLMethod);
    if(mSSLContext == NULL) {
        ERROR(Log::eNetwork, "Failed to initialize SLS_CTX. TLS Unavaliable.");
        ERROR(Log::eNetwork, ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err));
    } else
        INFO(Log::eNetwork, "Initialized SSL Context.");

    SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(mSSLContext, "ALL");

    //Load the SSL Certificates
    rxUInt ret = 0;
    ret = SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(mSSLContext, mCACertificateFile.c_str(), SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    if(ret <=0 ) {
        ERROR(Log::eNetwork, "Failed to read ssl sertificate. We should exit.");
        ERROR(Log::eNetwork, ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err));
    } else
        INFO(Log::eNetwork, "SSL Certificate read complete. OK!");

    //Load the private key file
    ret = SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(mSSLContext, mPrivateKeyFile.c_str(), SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    if(ret <=0 ) {
        ERROR(Log::eNetwork, "Failed to read private key file. We should exit.");
        ERROR(Log::eNetwork, ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err));
    } else
        INFO(Log::eNetwork, "Private Key read complete. OK!");

    if(!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(mSSLContext)) {
        ERROR(Log::eNetwork, "Private key does not match the SSL Certificate. We should exit.");
        ERROR(Log::eNetwork, ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err));
    } else
        INFO(Log::eNetwork, "Private Key and SSL Certificate Matched. OK!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1 7  1443513828.4800 (0.0000)  C>SV3.3(64)  Handshake
>   Unknown SSL content type 72

My guess is that you are sending some plain data on the connection, i.e. write to the plain socket instead to the SSL socket. This is just a guess because you did not provide any code but looking for such error one finds issues like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172415/java-netty-unknown-ssl-content-type-error).

Comment: I have added some code in my original post. I hope that might give you a little more hint.

Comment: @VikasSood: it looks more a problem of the client sending data the server does not like, so the server side code does not help much.

Comment: Client could be any HTML5 Websocket application. I use a simple javascript to connect.

Comment: @VikasSood: it would be useful to see a packet capture of the connection (upload to cloudshark.org)